# How to identify pinouts of my transformer with (2 +3) wire on primary side and (2+2)wire on secondary side?

Tags: power-supply, power, transformer, pinout, step-down

I got a Transformer from  old DVD player. the primary sites have 2 wire for main powers and other three winding and on the another side I have 2 pair of wire.

Comment: Are the wires color-coded at all? Perhaps you could include a photo of the transformer in question.

Comment: One test I find useful for this sort of thing is to apply a 12 V AC signal (from a variac perhaps) to the primary windings once identified. Then 1/10th the output voltage will appear on each secondary. This assumes 120 VAC primary. It's more forgiving of connection mistakes and often less dangerous that applying mains directly to the winding you hope is the primary :)

Answer (score 1):

For international use, mains transformers would typically accommodate 100VAC/120VAC/240VAC, maybe with 115 or 230VAC, so I would expect the primary taps to reflect that. Hopefully you made note of which tap was appropriate for your region. If you are in a 240V region you can just use the highest voltage tap (typically the highest resistance primary pair that shows continuity). There may be a screen wire, color coded appropriately, that won't show continuity to any of the other windings.

(That hassle is generally gone now, with the ubiquitous switching power supplies that can accommodate a drooping Japanese 100VAC mains up to a somewhat high 240VAC mains. At most they may require a single switch change.)

The secondaries should be easy to figure out once you've checked them out with an ohmmeter, and measured the volts once you've applied the correct voltage to the primary.

I would guess (but not having looked at any DVD player schematics) that there would be a relatively high voltage winding for the motors etc. and a relatively low voltage winding for the analog and digital ASIC circuitry.

Answer (score 0):

1. Bell out the windings to confirm which ones are shared.
2. Connect all wires to a terminal strip.
3. You say you have identified the primary winding so wire it up with a low current (1 A) fuse in series to a mains plug on a lead of 2 m or so.
4. Position the transformer 2 m away from the mains socket, don you safety glasses and plug in.
5. If the transformer buzzes loudly, smokes or makes noise then unplug immediately and start again.
6. With your meter on AC volts, measure the AC voltage on each pair of windings apart from the primary.

Comment: What is "belling out" a winding? Is that perhaps using the continuity-with-tone setting on a multi-meter to discover which conductors have continuity with others?

Comment: Yes, sorry. It's an old-fashioned term used by electricians who would use a battery and bell for continuity checks.

Comment: Ah, excellent! I find traditional trade terms like that enrich my sense of the practical nature of our work and serve as reminders we didn't always have digital test devices. I'm keeping that one in store :) One of my first electrical devices was an electromagnetic bell my father gave me as a youngster. So I've performed this test many times in its original form it turns out :)